# DSP - Sinewave: what is $2\pi f t $?

Tags: dsp-core

I am a beginner in DSP and is familiar with $\sin(\theta)$ declaration (as studied in trigonometry) - where $\theta$ is the angle it makes with X - axis. Please tell me what does $\sin(2\pi f t  + \phi)$ equation means and how $\theta = 2\pi ft + \phi$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1D sinusoidal wave, time dependent, is described by the next formula:

$$
y(t) = A\sin(2\pi f t + \phi)
$$

The trick here is just the concept. When you use the formula $A\sin(\theta) $ you aren't specifying if $\theta$ is time-dependent and you are not thinking in the formula as a wave, but as a mere function. But when you use the argument $2\pi f t$ you are considering the angular frequency $2\pi f$ ($rad/s$), where $ f $ is the normal frequency, and the wave's phase $\phi$ (which represents a shift in the wave).

If you are working with a simple sine wave, you can assume a zero-shift, $\phi = 0$, and select a working frequency. Sample the wave and work normally with your DSP.

I hope it helps!

You can check sine wave description in [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave)

Comment: Thanks I understand better know. Is there any book that explains these basic principles? It would really help me a lot.

Comment: Any book about DSP is pretty good, you only need a strong background in math and, to start, some notions about waves (signals). If you feel confident you can start reading this [book](http://itl7.elte.hu/~zsolt/Oktatas/editable_Digital_Signal_Processing_Principles_Algorithms_and_Applications_Third_Edition.pdf). I found it pretty amazing for basic-intermediate level. Bests!

Comment: Thanks for the link. It really helps me in my first step towards self-learning DSP

Comment: @Prakash 2πf = ω, which is angular frequency in radians/sec.  So a simpler formula is $\sin(\omega t)$, which shows more clearly that you're just stretching or squishing the time axis of the sin wave to make it oscillate faster or slower.  So the 2π is just a scaling factor from normal frequency to angular frequency.